Bottom Sheet Appearing Behind Tab Bar in React Native with Expo Tabs
I'm working on a React Native app with a bottom sheet, and the tab bar is implemented using expo-router tabs. The issue is that when I open the bottom sheet, it renders behind the tab bar instead of above it.
Tab Bar Setup (_layout.js with expo-router)
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import { icons } from '../../constants';
import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';

const TabIcon = ({ icon, color, focused }) => {
  return (
    <View className="items-center justify-center gap-2">
      <Image
        source={icon}
        resizeMode="contain"
        tintColor={color}
        className="w-6 h-6"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const TabLayout = () => {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1">
      <Tabs
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#8B4513', // Coffee brown color
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#666666',
          tabBarBackground: () => (
            <BlurView tint="dark" intensity={100} className=" flex-1 " />
          ),
          tabBarStyle: {
            position: 'absolute',
            borderTopWidth: 0, // Avoid double border
            zIndex:1,
          },
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
            height: 130,
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            borderBottomColor: 'rgba(24, 24, 27, 1)',

          },
          headerTitleAlign: 'left',
          headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 30,       // Adjust font size
            fontWeight: 'bold', // Font weight
            color: 'white',     // Font color
            paddingTop: 1,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="menu"
          options={{
            title: 'Menu',
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.home} color={color} focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="orders"
          options={{
            title: 'My Orders',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.bookmark} color={color} focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="cart"
          options={{
            title: 'Cart',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.bookmark} color={color} focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="profile"
          options={{
            title: 'Profile',
            headerShown: true,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabIcon icon={icons.profile} color={color} focused={focused} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TabLayout;


Bottom Sheet Implementation
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { useCallback, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
    Extrapolation,
    interpolate,
    useAnimatedProps,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useSharedValue,
    withSpring,
    withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');

const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 50;

const BottomSheet = React.forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
    const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
    const active = useSharedValue(false);

    const scrollTo = useCallback((destination) => {
        'worklet';
        active.value = destination !== 0;

        translateY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
    }, []);

    const isActive = useCallback(() => {
        return active.value;
    }, []);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ scrollTo, isActive }), [scrollTo, isActive]);

    const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
        .onStart(() => {
            context.value = { y: translateY.value };
        })
        .onUpdate((event) => {
            translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
            translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
            if (translateY.value > -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200) {
                scrollTo(-400);
            } else if (translateY.value < -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) {
                scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
            }
        });

    const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        const borderRadius = interpolate(
            translateY.value,
            [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + 50, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
            [25, 5],
            Extrapolation.CLAMP
        );

        return {
            borderRadius,
            transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
        };
    });

    const rBackdropStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            opacity: withTiming(active.value ? 1 : 0),
        };
    }, []);

    const rBackdropProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
        return {
            pointerEvents: active.value ? 'auto' : 'none',
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Animated.View
                onTouchStart={() => {
                    // Dismiss the BottomSheet
                    scrollTo(0);
                }}
                animatedProps={rBackdropProps}
                style={[
                    {
                        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
                    },
                    rBackdropStyle,
                ]}
            />
            <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[styles.bottomSheetContainer, rBottomSheetStyle]}
                >
                    <View style={styles.line} />
                    {children}
                </Animated.View>
            </GestureDetector>
        </>
    );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomSheetContainer: {
        height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#18181b',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    line: {
        width: 75,
        height: 4,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginVertical: 15,
        borderRadius: 2,
    },
});

export default BottomSheet;


The bottom sheet works fine, but it slides up behind the tab bar, making its content partially hidden. I’ve tried:

Adjusting the zIndex and elevation properties of both the bottom sheet and parent views.
Wrapping the bottom sheet in different containers with styles to prioritize its rendering.

None of these resolved the issue.
What I Need:
I want the bottom sheet to render above the tab bar so that the sheet content is fully visible. How can I achieve this while using Expo's tabs?
Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

As I think the problem in a place where you try to render your sheet. I did not see where a bottomSheet component was called.
I think you can try to call it not inside from TabLayout. It must be on the same level or higher.
modal example
It could be something like on the screen. Also here I use a popular bottom sheet library, you can try it too
https://gorhom.dev/react-native-bottom-sheet/modal/usage
